# C++ FMT issue formatting a custom abstract class

Tags: c++, std, fmt

I'm working on an events system for a personal project and I'm trying to make the events be logged to a console as easy as `LOG(event)`.

In this case, events are defined by an `Event` class which has some methods and a `virtual ToString()` function that returns a string with the event info and whatever I like to output on each event. This class is expanded further by defining specific event classes that inherit from `Event` class and that define the `ToString()` function according to what each event does and what variables it has.

So my `LOG` macro calls a static Log class' function to display the message in a console by converting the arguments into a string, like this:

```
#define LOG(...) Log::DisplayLog(LogUtils::StringFromArgs(__VA_ARGS__))
```

It's done like this because `DisplayLog()` receives also other info parameters that are not important for my problem.

The `LogUtils::StringFromArgs()` function converts the arguments to a string using *fmt* by doing the next:

```
template<typename FormatString, typename... Args>
inline std::string StringFromArgs(const FormatString& fmt, const Args &... args)
{
    char arg_string[1024];
    memset(arg_string, 0, sizeof(arg_string));
    fmt::format_to(arg_string, fmt, args...);
    return std::string(arg_string);
}
```

So, as I use fmt for this, I thought that making the log of an event as I want it would be easy, following the *fmt* guidelines, the idea was to set a formatter for the event class:

```
template<typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Event, T>::value, char>> : fmt::formatter<std::string>
{
    template<typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) { return ctx.begin(); }

    template<typename FormatCtx>
    auto format(const T& event, FormatCtx& ctx) // also tried Event& instead of T&
    {
        return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{0}", event.ToString());
        // also tried:
        //return fmt::formatter<std::string>::format(event.ToString(), ctx);
    }

};
```

However, this is not working, when I try to do `LOG(event)` of a specific event class (let's say "event" is `WindowResizedEvent` inheriting from `Event` class) I keep having the same error from fmt because it can't format the event (also I tried to add a `const char*()` operator in the `Event` class and still the same):

[image]
The "Argument 2" is the "event" argument (as I said I have some other arguments in the middle that aren't important on this problem).

Does anyone knows how can I get to format this without specifying a formatter for each type of event class? Because it would be always the same code for each event type.

Comment: `LOG(event)`: Your macro/function expects a format string as first argument.

Comment: No, the problem is on the fmt::format_to() function called from StringFromArgs(), not in the macro, the macro doesn't expects a type of variable

Comment: The second argument to `fmt::format_to` must be convertible to a format string. The way you presented your code, `LOG` just passes on its first argument to the second one of `format_to`. `Event` does not look like a valid format string or convertible to one.

Comment: Ah yes, but the point is how to do that (as answered below)

Comment: The whole point of `fmt` is that you can write a format string like e.g. `"Error at line {} in object {}."` and have the `{}` be replaced with a string encoding some object passed to the `format_to` function. If you don't need such a format string, then you simply want a conversion operator to `std::string`.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought, simply doing an operator in the `Event` class converting an event to a const char* or a string but fmt still gives the same error.

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. What I mean is that you don't need any `fmt` at all if you don't want to use format strings. Just have `StringFromArgs` concatenate all the arguments after conversion to `std::string`.

Comment: Maybe you should give some explicit examples of what you expect the `LOG` macro to produce for single and multiple arguments. I am not entirely clear on what you expect.

Comment: Aaah yes, I see what you mean, I can give it a try. Yeah so the point is to use it as `LOG(event)` if I don't want to specify any further strings and as a `LOG("Whatever Message {}", value)` for other cases, that's why I'm dealing with fmt, but I think what you say makes pretty much sense

Comment: In that case I would add another overload for that case and let it either convert to `std::string` or call `format_to` with `"{}"` format string. Making the overload resolution work correctly might be a bit tricky. Probably needs SFINAE or a `requires` clause to exclude arguments convertible to format strings. I haven't considered the details.

Comment: Okay thanks, that actually worked perfectly :) ... I didn't needed any SFINAE for the Event-inheriting classes (at least for now, I'll see in the future if other types give issues), so what I did is, as you said, overload the function and have one that gets one arg T& and another one that gets the format_string and the args, and with that I could make it work... If you want to make your answer actually an answer down the page I'll be happy to mark it as an answer :) (I don't know if I can mark 2 answers because the @vitaut one was helpful too, I'll see if it's an option).

Comment: Is a bit crazy because the overloading is an easy & simple solution that I didn't thought of before :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string should be passed as `fmt::format_string` and not as a template parameter. Here's a working example (https://godbolt.org/z/xYehaMWsG):

```cpp
#include <fmt/format.h>

struct Event {
  virtual std::string ToString() const = 0;
};

struct MyEvent : Event {
  std::string ToString() const override {
    return "foo";
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<
    T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Event, T>::value, char>>
    : fmt::formatter<std::string> {
  auto format(const T& event, fmt::format_context& ctx) {
    return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", event.ToString());
  }
};

#define LOG(...) fmt::print("{}", StringFromArgs(__VA_ARGS__))

template <typename... T>
std::string StringFromArgs(fmt::format_string<T...> fmt, T&&... args) {
  return fmt::format(fmt, std::forward<T>(args)...);
}

int main() {
  LOG("{}", MyEvent());
}
```

Note that it's better to use `fmt::format` instead of `fmt::format_to` if you are formatting to a string. In fact you can replace `StringFromArgs` with `fmt::format`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked :) ... Additionally, is there a way to avoid the "{}" parameter? Since it expects a fmt::format_string I understand that it needs that string, but could I arrange it in a way in which I could just do `LOG(event)`? Is there any fmt type that would allow me to do that?

Comment: Do you mean overload LOG so that it takes both format string and a single argument without format string? If yes then I wouldn't recommend it because of ambiguity.

Comment: No, I wasn't unaware that there was a way to overload macros... I wanted to know if fmt supports passing some general type instead of a format string, I know it doesn't makes a lot of sense or that is very generic but I have very little experience with fmt

Comment: Maybe it's worth trying by making the DisplayLog() function to work as a template or actually overloading that function